# Issue when inserting a formula into a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to insert formulas into cells using this following code:

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=ISERROR(IF(O" & ActiveCell.Row & "=M; _
    LEFT(O" & ActiveCell.Row & ";LEN(O" & ActiveCell.Row & ")-1)*1000000; _
    LEFT(O" & ActiveCell.Row & ";LEN(O" & ActiveCell.Row & ")-1)*1000000000);" & vide & ")"
```

(vide is a string variable) but it keeps returning Application defined or Object defined error.

Thanks !

Comment: Change the `;` to `,`

Comment: And `" & vide & "` to `""" & vide & """`

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have changed the code to 
ActiveCell.Formula = "=ISERROR(IF(O" & ActiveCell.Row & "=M,LEFT(O" & ActiveCell.Row & ",LEN(O" & ActiveCell.Row & ")-1)*1000000,LEFT(O" & ActiveCell.Row & ",LEN(O" & ActiveCell.Row & ")-1)*1000000000),""" & vide & """)" 
But I still have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change `;` to `,`

Change `" & vide & "` to `""" & vide & """`

Change `M` to `""M""`

Change `ISERROR` to `IFERROR`

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IFERROR(IF(O" & ActiveCell.Row & "=""M"",LEFT(O" & ActiveCell.Row & ",LEN(O" & ActiveCell.Row & ")-1)*1000000,LEFT(O" & ActiveCell.Row & ",LEN(O" & ActiveCell.Row & ")-1)*1000000000),""" & vide & """)"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because of your local settings, you use `;` unstead of `,`.

If you must use `;`, then try replacing:

```
ActiveCell.Formula
```

with:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaLocal
```

Also, I like to use `Chr(34)` to get the `"`.
So at the end change your formula to:

```
...1000000000);" & Chr(34) & vide & Chr(34) & ")"
```

Comment: Still missing two problems, before I can delete mine.

Comment: @ScottCraner LOL :) don;t delete yours, I might have missed them so far...